# How many community mods were active in the past 20m?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Being a community moderator means that I routinely check Skeptics, the site I am responsible for.

One of the bits of information I need to know often, is pretty hard to reach: *the number of currently browsing moderators*.

This is of course not quite useful on large sites, but on smaller ones it's not uncommon to discover that no one is browsing at any particular time.

Right now, it's possible to know this info, but it's quite uncomfortable to get to:

1. I can go in our common chat room or teacher's lounge and ping my colleagues to know if they are around. I don't like this because it's disruptive.
2. I can go to `/admin` look at the "Last Seen" column, click on in twice to sort, and count which mods were seen, say, less than 20 minutes ago. Pretty annoying.

   [image]

What I would *really* like instead is to have that number always visible, or at least visible where it matters (e.g. admin, flag list, mod menus). Example mock up for you to <del>hate</del> love:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how this is useful.

Comment: Why, exactly, do you feel like you_«need to know constantly»_ how many other mods are surfing? How does this knowledge affect your actions as a moderator?

Comment: the [users/moderators](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint has this info, an userscript might do?

Comment: Is this to justify booting those that are only moderators in name and are just not really doing anything?

Comment: @random If that was the motivation the existing tools would be more than adequate. The moderator history page shows detailed stats describing how much load each moderator is shouldering in the last week/month/year and even highlights the slackers in orange or red to the degree of their shame. Clearly the OP has something else in mind here, I just can think what the use case would be.

Comment: As a regular user this would be nice to see which of the mods are only there because they want to say they're moderators

Comment: I'd find this useful on occasion; nice to know if there's someone around if you need to handle a situation *now* but could use a second set of eyes if possible. Though, I'm not sure the activity criteria for the dashboard are sufficient for this.

Comment: @Caleb what Shog said, basically. I don't need to know it constantly, however often enough that it's annoying to do otherwise. In fact, sometimes I find myself taking action in order to stop an ongoing situation where I could consult but don't since I am not sure anyone else is around.

Comment: @Shog9 Easy solution. Look in chat, look on that admin dashboard. Ping the most recent person. I don't see how this is any better or even different.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I gave two more ways to find out this info, but, as I said in my question, this is about making the information more convenient. This adds value to the site, believe it or not :-)

Comment: (If you don't want to disrupt common chat room or tl) You can maintain a private room like "Skeptics Moderators" belonging to your site where your active colleagues can be available.

Comment: @Pandya Many active moderators don't use chat.

Comment: Also keep in mind "seen" and "active" are different things. One might just open a browser with saved tabs, and never really visit the site itself; or visit the site just for quick overview, not having time to do any actions.

Comment: You say this isn't aimed at large sites.  On my smaller sites I don't have a problem scanning down that "last seen" column on the mod dashboard; I don't need to sort it first for five people.  I wouldn't want another random number in the top bar demanding my attention; the bogus review count is bad enough.  This seems like something that'd be better as a userscript.